# "characteristic" vs. "typical"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *characteristic* and *typical*?
I've seen that they both are used with kinda the same structure (be characteristic/typical of sb/sth)

Like: "This hospitality is characteristic of him." Or "Being late is typical of him."

But it seems to me that *typical* is usually used to show annoyance, but *characteristic* is not, right?

I wanted to know if it is possible to use *typical* with just the same meaning as *characteristic*, i.e. not to show annoyance, in a sentence like "This hospitality is typical of him".

And what about using *characteristic* to show annoyance, in a sentence like "It's characteristic of him to ruin his friends' parties"?

Comment: 'Characteristic!' is unusual as a stand-alone comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the nine drop-down examples of usage at the entry for [*typical*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/typical) at Oxforddictionaries.com, you will see that the word can readily be used in both positive and negative contexts.

However, I think the implied *intensity* of the negative sense is often greater with *typical* than it is with *characteristic,* which is often used in more neutral contexts. *Typical* is therefore often used in situations where the speaker is accustomed to disparaging others.

Hence I'd be much more likely to say

> "It's typical of him to ruin his friends' parties"

than

> "It's characteristic of him to ruin his friends' parties"

Comment: The fox needs a hat.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - For you, Edwin...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Where is *your* hat, BTW?

Comment: I couldn't compete with that, so I'll not try. When does the film come out?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - What does the fox say? Find out in *The Interview* (Sony Pictures).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Not yet a 20th-century fox...

Comment: Catchy. But can we call those English _words_? (I know some who would.)

Comment: IMO, this does not answer the question. To say only "*the implied intensity of the negative sense is often greater with typical than it is with characteristic*" does not capture what the essential difference in meaning is. IMO, @MystiSingha's answer does capture it: *typical* as reflecting frequency of occurrence and *characteristic* as reflecting an essential quality/character of the thing.

Comment: @Drew - The adjective 'characteristic' has more than one meaning. For instance, Merriam-Webster defines it thus: *typical of a person, thing, or group : showing the special qualities or traits of a person, thing, or group*. You seem to be focusing solely on the second definition.

Comment: Yes, of course it has multiple meanings, as does the adjective *typical*. But the difference between the two that Mysti points to is a bigger, more "*characteristic*" difference than the one you point to, IMO. ;)

Answer (score 4):

> As their spelling and meaning implies, there is a close link between
>   the words **characteristic** and **character**, meaning the *essential nature
>   of a thing,* and in fact both words come from the ancient Greek **kharackter**, meaning a "symbol or imprint on the soul.

- stripes characteristic of the zebra

> When something is typical, it is *common, regular, expected*.

- a typical romantic poem
- a typical case of arteritis
- It's typical (**expected**) of him to ruin his friends' parties.

Comment: This is the correct answer, IMO. The other answers (so far) do not seem at all appropriate to me.

Answer (score 1):

*Typical* when used to describe somethin objectively is neutral, you could use either *typical* or *characteristic*.

> Spraying ink when in danger is a typical/characteristic behaviour of squids.

But you can also use *typical* to make reference to a steretoype, then it would have a negative connotation. *Characteristic* isn't used in this way.

> He's the typical macho-man.